# Merge branch with cherry-picked commit from local branch without any conflict

Tags: git, merge, git-cherry-pick

When I cherry-pick commits from another branch, and then try to merge it. If
more changed have been applied I have merge conflicts.

A good example, is if I have follow the 'gitflow' cliché way of doing git
(master, develop, feature/bugfix, hotfix). Here's the steps:

- I merge a `bugfix` into `develop`
- I merge some more feature into `develop`
- I cherry-pick my old `bugfix` and apply it as a `hotfix` onto `master`
- If I merge `master` back into `develop` I get a merge conflict.
- If I checkout my `bugfix` merge commit, then merge `master` (thus creating this
  "in-between" merge), and then merge this "in-between" merge into `develop`
  everything works without any conflict.

Some how git figures out the cherry-pick if no change happen after. But if more
changes were added, it's the end of the world for git.

Here's an ascii schema of my problem C' is the cherry-picked C:

(keys: ✔ = no conflict, ✘ = conflict)

```
     +-------------------->✘ <--+
     |                          |
     |                          |
     |              ✔<--------+ |
     |              ^         | |
     |              |         +-+--+
     |              |         | M2 +<-----+
     |              |         +-+--+      |
     |              +           ^       +-+-+
     | +----------->✔<--------+ |       | D |
     | |                      | |       +-+-+
   +-+-++                     +-+--+      ^
   | Ma +<----+         +---->+ M1 +------+
   +-+--+     |         |     +-^--+
     ^      +-+--+    +-+-+     |
     |      | C' |    | C |     |
     |      +-+--+    +-+-+     |
     |        ^         ^       |
     |        |         |       |
     |      +-+--+    +-+-+     |
     |      | B' |    | B |     |
     |      +-+--+    +-+-+     |
     |        ^         ^       |
   +-+--+     |         |       |
   | A  +-----+---------+-------+
   +-+--+     |         |       |
     |        |         |       |
     |        |         |       |
     +        +         +       +

Master     Cherry-   Bugfix     Develop
           Picked
           Hotfix
```

Here's my script that create this situation:

```
git init
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nqux\nquux" > file
git add file
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b develop
git branch second-feature
git checkout -b first-feature
echo -e "foo1\nbar\nbaz\nqux\nquux" > file
git commit -m "First feature" file
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff -m "Merge first feature" first-feature
git checkout second-feature
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz2\nqux\nquux" > file
git commit -m "Second feature" file
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff -m "Merge second feature" second-feature
git tag before-bugfix
git checkout -b bugfix
echo -e "foo1\nbar\nbaz2\nqux\nquux1" > file
git commit -m "Bugfix (part I)" file
echo -e "foo1\nbar\nbaz2\nqux\nquux2" > file
git commit -m "Bugfix (part II)" file
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff -m "Merge bugfix" bugfix
git checkout -b third-feature
echo -e "foo1\nbar\baz2\nqux\nquux3" > file
git commit -m "Third feature" file
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff -m "Third feature" third-feature
git checkout master
git cherry-pick -x before-bugfix..bugfix
```

If I do, I get:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge --no-ff master
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

If I do, I get:

```
$ git checkout -b new-master bugfix
$ git merge --no-ff -m "In-between Merge" master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
$ git merge --no-ff -m "Merge master" new-master
Already up-to-date!
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

Is there a way to solve this in one merge without any conflict?

I tried different merge startegies but it didn't work. I tried to merge master and
bugfix at the same time into develop, I still get a conflict.

Comment: Why would you merge `master` back into `develop`?

Comment: @kowsky in this dummy example it makes no sense. In reality, because you want to add more commit on master and avoid conflicts in the future, or because you want to literally follow the 'git flow' doctrine, ... There are many cases where this could be relevant.

Comment: In GitFlow, you never merge back `master` into `develop`. The only thing that ever is branched away from `master` are hotfixes, and those are usually cherry-picked into develop. Thus, `develop` will never contain any `Merge branch develop into master` merge commits. See [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: @kowsky, you're right nevermind. I do on my personal projects. A reason to do that would be if you wanted your next merge from develop into master to be conflictless (without releasing develop).

Answer (score 0):

To do what you expect, git would have to track the whole history of the merged branches, to recognize the equivalent commit and skip it. It does not do it, it only uses 3 commits from the history: the parents and the "merge base" - common ancestor of parents.

You could guide it so, if you wish:

- create a temporary "merge" branch: `git checkout -b master_with_develop master`
- merge the `develop` just before the cherry-picked commit
- merge the cherry-picked commit alone. This would hopefully recognize that the changes are same and do not conflict. At worst, the conflict will be smaller and easier to comprehend
- merge the rest of `develop`
- reset to `develop` and merge `master_with_develop` - it would be fast-forward (you could also mark it as `--no-ff` to create explicit merge commit)

You could check [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) tool which tries to do the procedure above automatically